# I can't read this cover of a precedent case

Tags: precedent

Embarrassing, I have a very simple question. I can't interprete this cover of a precedent case because I am an English learner. Please give me your help. In the middle of the image I attached below,

"Louis J. Hoffman, Hoffman Patent Firm of Scottsdale, Arizona, argued for plaintiff-appelle. On the brief was Lan B Crosby, Susman Godfrey LLP, of Seattle, Washington."

In this sentence, Is Louis the plaintiff-appelle? or... Louis is the lawyer??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hoffman and Crosby are both lawyers. The plaintiff-appellee was DDR Holdings LLC. An appellate case involves both a written brief and an oral argument before the court. Hoffman did the oral argument, and Crosby worked on the brief (Hoffman likely also worked on the brief).